# Create new user programmatically with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Devise to manage users in my rails app. I have a button available to admin users which leads to a form that allows them to create other admin user accounts.

When the form is submitted this code is called:

```
@user = User.new(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])
@user.admin = true
@user.save
```

It doesn't seem to be working correctly as when I sign out and try to sign in with the new admin account it fails. I'm guessing the above code isn't the correct way to create a new user with Devise.

Edit:

Logs

```
Started POST "/users/13/create_admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-16 17:01:38 +0100
Processing by UsersController#create_admin as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VpP78Zy8SAcyC1Mgg6hEjG2I5jqNzIHXQGtbjUzDYVE=", "users"=>{"email"=>"test@admin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered users/create_admin.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Here's my form:

```
  <%= form_for :users, :html => { :id => "signup-form" }, :url => create_admin_user_path do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<div class="actions">
  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-success" %></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the user created in the database? When you attempt to log in with the new account, does it indicate that the password is wrong? Can you run a password reset with the new account's email address?

Comment: is your admin really a "User", or is it an "AdminUser" or "Administrator" ?

Comment: Can you please post your User modal?

Comment: @JamesChevalier I checked the db and it's not being added to the Users table.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott It's just a user. There is an 'admin' column on the user table which I set to 'true' for admin users.

Comment: there should be some errors in the logs when you call save on user, I am sure it can't be a clean request with no errors.

Comment: I get completed 200 in the logs. I'm adding the logs to the question now. The only strange thing I see it no mention of the admin property.

Comment: change to `@user.save!` -- you'll get the reason why it's not saving then for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're actually posting

```
"users"=>{"email"=>"test@admin.com", "password"=>""}
```

So, you should be

```
@user = User.new(:email => params[:users][:email], :password => params[:users][:password], :password_confirmation => params[:users][:password_confirmation]))
@user.admin = true
@user.save
```

Comment: I put the ! after save and got: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank. So I suspect your correct. However with the code you posted I get: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Got it, should have been :user not :users. Working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about `User.new(params[:user])` then whitelist attributes in model, or filter using `params[:user].splice`?

Answer (score 1):

In new devise one should remove password from params hash. If password is blank. E.g. we want to edit profile but do not change password.
Or devise will fail validation.

```
if params[:user][:password].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password)
  params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
end
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) for more details.